# Synonym of "High-Level" in "High-Level Ideas/Description/Method"

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, vocabulary

I'm writing a paper and we have the following quote.

> see Section 1.3.4 for a high-level description of the method and Section 2.1 for the specific application.

Basically, we're using a general method which we outline in Section 1.3.4; in Section 2.1 we describe our application of this method. As a native English speaker, this sentence seems fine to me. However, someone who is French <sup>1</sup> suggested that we change it with the following comment.

> for a high-level description of the method », maybe replace « high-level » by some other adjective, such as « precise ». (Feels more modest.)

We certainly are not intending to be arrogant! Rather we are describing the ideas at an abstract level.

So my question is two-fold.

> (a) Do people agree that this may come off as arrogant (not modest)?
> (b) What synonyms for "high level" are there? <sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> : but at least fluent enough in English to be at a university in Austria in a department which uses English as its main language.

<sup>2</sup> : other than perhaps "abstract" (but not sure it means exactly the same thing...) I am struggling to think of any; a well-known internet search engine has not been as helpful as one might expect

Comment: Accuracy is not immodest. Abstract is the usual word, but there's also summary, executive summary, overview, and general description.

Comment: I edited your question to turn ^[1] and ^[2] into actual superscripts. This is done in the following way: `<sup>1</sup>`.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you. SE seems to use _some_ Markdown (and even links to more general Markdown commands), but doesn't do all. What I wrote would give a cross-referencing footnote in a Markdown document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that ***high-level*** *description* is somewhat redundant. I know it's possible to have a ***detailed*** description, but if *description* is used on its own, without qualification, I would assume it would be *high-level* anyway.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*description*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/description):

> **1 b** : a statement or account giving the characteristics of someone or something : a descriptive statement or account
>        // The review was little more than a *description* of the film's plot.

As such, I see nothing wrong with just the following:

> a *description* of the method

---

However, if some kind of qualification is required, you could used [*general*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/general) rather than *high-level*:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **6** : relating to, determined by, or concerned with main elements rather than limited details
>     // bearing a general resemblance to the original

Using *general* is more understandable than *high-level*, which might not necessarily be easily understood by everyone:

> a ***general*** *description* of the method

---

To provide contrast to *general description*, add what was mentioned in the definition of *general* as contrasting with it:

> See Section 1.3.4 for a **general** description of the method and Section 2.1 for **details** of the specific application.

Comment: These are good suggestions, thank you. I'll leave this unaccepted for the time being as it's possible someone will come along with a suggestion which I feel serves my purpose better. If not, I'll accept this shortly :)